# Postgresql JDBC driver rollback batch query when error occurs

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am using JDBC postgresql driver. When sending batch query to database, postgres driver rollbacks everything when error occurs and result is array with Statement.Execute_FAILED only.

```
 try (Connection connection = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(UPSERT_THESIS)) {
        for (SomeObject d : data) {
            stmt.setString(1, d.getId());
            stmt.setString(2, d.getName());
            stmt.addBatch();
        }
        int[] result = stmt.executeBatch();}
```

I got result [-3,-3,-3]. It does not matter if autocommit is on/off.

When using other databases, like Mysql, there is no rollback, every statement is processed and saved in database except the one when error occurs. So i got result array with mixed Statement.Success_NOINFO and Statement.Execute_FAILED ([1,1,-3,1]).

Is this  postgres jdbc normal behaviour? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Yes this is the expected behaviour of a transaction: either all statements succeed or none.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So,why this works with mysql? This two databases have different mechanism of transactions?

Comment: Because Postgres has a much stricter (some might argue: "correcter") opinion on what a transaction is than MySQL.

Comment: You can use savepoints before critical statements, then you can roll back and error and keep the active transaction.